# Understanding Starred Expression

Tags: python

I am currently trying to run some reinforcement learning algorithms on basic game. However the problem is more related to python syntax than RL.
The problem has to to do with starred expression. Can someone explain me what the error in the code given below is.

```
rewards= []

#2 for life or until learning is stopped
for episode in range(total_episode):
    #Reset the env.
    state= env.reset()
    step=0
    done= False
    total_rewards=0

    for step in range(max_steps):
        #Choose an action in current world given state(s)
        exp_exp_tradeoff= random.uniform(0,1)
        #Taking max q value
        if exp_exp_tradeoff>epsilon:
            action= np.argmax(qtable[state,:])
            #Else doing a random choice--> exploration            
        else:
            action=env.action_space.sample()

        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        # Update Q(s,a):= Q(s,a) + lr [R(s,a) + gamma * max Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)]
        # qtable[new_state,:] : all the actions we can take from new state

        qtable[state,action]= qtable[state, action] 
        +learning_rate*(reward+gamma*np.max(qtable[new_state,:]
        -qtable[state,action]))

        total_rewards +=reward

        #New state is the now the current state
        state=new_state

        if done == True:
            break

    epsilon= min_epsilon+(max_epsilon-min_epsilon)
    *np.exp(-decay_rate*episode)

print("Score over time: " + str(sum(rewards)/total_episodes))
print(qtable)
```

The error given is :

```
 File "<ipython-input-15-fb7ce8ca2071>", line 43
    print(qtable)
               ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: There may be some parentheses missing 3-4 lines above?

Comment: Yes, there was a misisng paranthesis. I wonder why the error was pointed at the print command though. Will you be able to tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is there:

```
epsilon= min_epsilon+(max_epsilon-min_epsilon)
*np.exp(-decay_rate*episode)
```

It should be on the same line:

```
epsilon= min_epsilon+(max_epsilon-min_epsilon)*np.exp(-decay_rate*episode)
```

Or wrapped with parenthesis:

```
epsilon= (min_epsilon+(max_epsilon-min_epsilon)
    *np.exp(-decay_rate*episode))
```

The error shows on your `print` line, because due to you using the asterisk syntax, Python's parser continued to parse in hope of finding a valid syntax and failed when it was obvious it wouldn't be valid.

Comment: This did solve the previous issue but its giving me a new error of multiplying a sequence with a type float.
` 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c8f14da6ac8d> in <module>
     
---> 29         qtable[state, action] = qtable[state, action] + learning_rate * (reward + gamma * np.max(qtable[new_state, :]) - qtable[state, action])
     30 
     31         total_rewards += reward


**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'**